# Signal after processing with FFT and then IFFT is not the same

Tags: c++, signal-processing, fft, convolution

I want to make a sound simulation of a virtual scene. Therefore I want to convolute the impulse response my system calculates with an input signal from a simple .wav-file in a frequency dependant manner. As far as I understand DSP the best way is to use the FFT to convert the input signal into its frequency spectrum, somehow apply the impulse response function to it and iFFT it back.

My problem is that after doing the FFT on my signal and afterwards the iFFT, the signal differs from the original input signal. The original sound is kind of recognizable in the new signal, but it is very "blurred" due to false numbers after FFT and iFFT. I took the "first" (in-place, breadth-first, decimation-in-frequency) implementation example of the FFT in C++ from http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform#C.2B.2B.

Here is the code of my inner code usage of the FFT implementation:

```
CArray signal = CArray(output_size);
for (int i = 0; i < format.FrameCount; ++i) {
   signal[i] = Complex((double)(is_8_bit ? sample_data_8[i] : sample_data_16[i]), 0);
}

fft(signal);
ifft(signal);
```

The following **typedefs** exist:

```
typedef std::complex<double> Complex;
typedef std::valarray<Complex> CArray;
```

Since I took the code from the above website, I assume that the mistake can't be within the implementation of the FFT. I assume that it has to do something with the data types of my input and/or the complex numbers.

Since my system does not implement "phases" and I read that they can be neglected and there can still be returned a useful value, I am initialising the complex numbers with the imaginary part of 0.

Is there a fundamental mistake I have made or is the fault in something like data types or rounding where it should not be?

Comment: what is the sampling rate?

Comment: @alexm The sample rate is 22050Hz.

Comment: This is only a shoot but to make FFT work correctly you need to feed it with 2^n samples.

Comment: On site you provided second FFT function is not working correctly for me!

Comment: @Logman Do you mean the "(in-place, breadth-first, decimation-in-frequency)" approach? This approach actually throws memory allocation exceptions for me at the moment; is that the same for you? The first "divide and conquer" was the one I was using. Sorry, should have additionally pointed that out. The first compiles and executes for me, but somehow seems to not give me the result I wanted. I also tried it with 48Hz and a 2^n sample and both had the similar result unfortunately.

Comment: Yes in-place is bad. But if you say that in-place throw you a memory allocation exception that mean you are not using 2^n samples. I checked in first FFT function you will not get error but result will be wrong. Please try your function on only 4 samples and check if they are correct.

Comment: Btw. If you remove normalization section from in-place it should work correct.

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried it with a 2^16 sample. Was probably kind of a bad test. But you are right. With only 4 samples it works for me and after removing the normalization section, the right values are returned. Do you know how it comes that I need 2^n values? - As far as I saw it is not a general rule for FFT. It is kind of a restriction I'd like to avoid. Did you try out the divide and conquer algorithm?

Comment: Yes d and c was wrong for not 2^n but not generate error (sorry for in-place i was thinking recursive - first and not recursive - second function) ;). On study we learn how to make FFT on paper (butterfly algorithm) and it has only one condition you need to have 2^n samples if you have less you need to add 0 for ex. signal (1,0,1,1,1) will be (1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0). If you satisfy I will write this as answer.

Comment: FFT is a family of algorithms that computes DFT maybe not all of them has 2^n limitations but what I learn right now from [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform) Cooley–Tukey algorithm has. You can always use some normal DFT algorithms to calculate not 2^n signal.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To get correct result you need to have 2^n samples. If you have less then 2^n samples just add zeros at the end of the signal. For example signal (1,0,1,1,1) will be (1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0).

Answer (score 0):

Please test if this is not only a scaling error. In many instances (but not all), the FFT and iFFT are implemented without the division by the sample number, thus for a signal of length `N`, only

```
iFFT(FFT(signal))/N
```

returns the original `signal`.

---

For serious transformational work, look up zero-padding and windowing.

Comment: The normalization part in the "decimation-of-frequency" algorithm was somehow the problem. If I insert a 2^n sample it works. I tried out to use the original source again, do iFFT(FFT(signal)) and then divide each sample by signal.size() but that did not get me the right result. If I misunderstood the /N part, please inform me about it. Thank you for the terms. I will look them up.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the right procedure. Either the variant with or the variant without division by N=signal.size() should work consistently. The documentation should show whether dyadic or general lengths are permissible. General lengths require larger libraries like FFTW or Spiral implementing several different FFT algorithms (Bluestein, Winograd, Rader(?)). Giving a non-dyadic length to a plain Cooley-Tukey implementation can give strange results.